# Any way to have clickable labels of Checkbox elements in Flow Screens?

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, checkbox

An input of Checkbox type can be added to a Flow Screen:

[image: checkbox screen shot]

but the output when the Flow is run will only accept clicks on the checkbox and not on the label. That is inconsistent with e.g. checkbox labels in LWCs and makes the screen harder to use i.e. offers poor usability.

Is there a way to solve this problem and make the labels clickable in screen flows?

Comment: I haven't tried this but did you look at [UnofficialSf.com Lightning Input](https://unofficialsf.com/lightninginput/)?

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. This does generate the simple idea of adding my own LWC that supports a clickable label - I'll try that.